# How to create a OData model with header "authorization" from Manifest

Tags: odata, sapui5

I would like to know how to create an OData model from manifest.json and bind with xml view.
But the OData expects a header "authorization" which is required to be passed for doing a GET.

Could you help how can I achieve the model-creation using the manifest itself and not doing an explicit get in my controllers?

Nandan

Comment: Hey I am not sure about the authorization but headers you can definitely pass in the manifest like this, "models": {
   "": {
    "dataSource": "mainService",
    "settings": {
     "defaultBindingMode": "TwoWay",
     "defaultCountMode": "Inline",
     "refreshAfterChange": false,
     "headers": {
            "myHeader1" : "value1",
            "myHeader2" : "value2"
        }
    }
   }
  } Let me know if this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot. This has worked for me. Could you also please share the source of this information so I can read through ?

Comment: Hey Nandan i did not find it in any documentation,So i tried adding headers directly in manifest and it worked.

Comment: @Nandan The `"settings"` object becomes the constructor "parameters" object while creating the model instance, in our case, [v2.ODataModel](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel). You can see `headers` there as a parameter which awaits map of headers.

Answer (score 1):

```
"models":{  
   "":{  
      "dataSource":"mainService",
      "settings":{  
         "defaultBindingMode":"TwoWay",
         "defaultCountMode":"Inline",
         "refreshAfterChange":false,
         "headers":{  
            "myHeader1":"value1",
            "myHeader2":"value2"
         }
      }
   }
}
```